# Unexplained LightHouse start_url audit error

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse, cacheapi

I'm running a PWA LightHouse audit with the ServiceWorker code below. The audit reports failures: -

- . Current page does not respond with a 200 when offline
- . start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline

The PWA is recognized as Installable.

I am using remote debugging.

The Chrome Network Tab says there was one access via ServiceWorker and a second via DiskCache.

Why is it going to Network/Disk when it is in cache?

```
const CACHE_NAME    = "BrotkrumenV1.0"

self.addEventListener('install',
    function (e) {
        e.waitUntil(
            caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) {
                return cache.addAll([
                    '/TravelManager.html',
                    '/hg.png',
                    '/gingerbreadhouse.png',
                    '/striped-witch-hat.png',
                    '/brotkrumen.css',
                    '/echo.js',
                    '/registerserviceworker.js',
                    '/brotkrumen.json',
                    '/TravelManagerPolyfill.js',
                    '/HandleMap.js'
                ]).then(() => self.skipWaiting());
            })
        );
    });

    self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) 
    {
        e.waitUntil(
            caches.keys().then((keyList) => {
                return Promise.all(keyList.map((key) => {
                    if (key !== CACHE_NAME) {
                        console.log('Removing cache', key);
                        return caches.delete(key);
                    }
                }));
            })
        );

        e.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
    });

    self.addEventListener('fetch', function (e) {

        console.log(e.request.url);

        e.respondWith(

            caches.match(e.request).then(function (response) {
                console.log("Request " + e.request.url);
                if (response) 
                    console.log("Response " + response.url);
                else 
                    console.log("No MATCH");

                return response || fetch(e.request);

            })

        );
    });
```

The manifest start_url should match what's in cache and pass the audit.

```
{
  "short_name": "Brotkrumen",
  "name": "Brotkrumen Web App",
  "description": "Native Background Geolocation POC",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "gingerbreadhouse.png",
      "sizes": "48x48 128x128 144x144 192x192 512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/TravelManager.html",
  "background_color": "#00ccdd",
  "theme_color": "#00ccdd",
  "display": "fullscreen"
}
```

Comment: What is the start_url in your manifest file and what is the path to your app? Is your app in a subfolder?

Comment: No Sub-folder. Path to App is localhost:8080 which may be the problem as IIS directs to TravelManager.html. But as that is the start URL in the manifest it "should" be ok.

Comment: I added the manifest above @Mathias

Comment: The start_url should be just the folder where your app is located, not a specific file e.g.  "start_url": "/"

Comment: @Mathias Rubbish! Sorry, I mean do you have a reference for that assertion?

Comment: see also: - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/start_url